# Preferred ES6 arrow function syntax formatting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have an `onChange` event handler that is shaping up like this:

```
(e) => (value => this.setState(prevState => ({
        form: {
            ...prevState.form,
            email: value
        }
    })))(e.target.value)
```

I minified it down to that from this

```
(e) => {
    let value = e.target.value;
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
        form: {
            ...prevState.form,
            password: value
        }
    }))
}
```

Neither of these are very appealing. I like the first one b/c it is 3 less lines of code but it also has a ton of parenthesis. Is there another variation I might be missing that can clean this up further? The use of the spread operator adds an extra paren, could this be removed somehow?

Thanks

Comment: very much the second one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could destructure out the value from the event and just do the `setState` as the only statement.

```
({ target: { value } }) => this.setState(prevState => ({
  form: {
    ...prevState.form,
    password: value
  }
}));
```

Comment: This is baller, destructure ftw. Thanks! I knew there was a better way. Whoever down voted can never use this :)

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would use this:

```
e => {
    let value = e.target.value;
    this.setState({
        form: {
            ...this.state.form,
            password: value
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just another idea for you :)

```
event => {
   const password = event.target.value;
   const form = { ...this.state.form, password };
   this.setState({ form });
}
```